# Spark Adding a column consisting of a tuple to a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.6 and I want to add a column to a dataframe. The new column actually is a constant sequence: Seq("-0", "-1", "-2", "-3")

Here is my original dataframe:

```
scala> df.printSchema()
```

> root
>   |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)
>   |-- test_name: string (nullable = true)

```
df.show()
```

> |user_name|       test_name|
>
> +------------+--------------------+
>
> |user1| SAT|
>
> | user9| GRE|
>
> | user7|MCAT|

I want to add this extra column (attempt) so that the new dataframe becomes:

> ```
> |user_name|test_name|attempt|
> +------------+--------------------+
> |user1| SAT|Seq("-0","-1","-2","-3")|
> | user9| GRE|Seq("-0","-1","-2","-3")
> | user7|MCAT|Seq("-0","-1","-2","-3")
> ```

How do I do that?

Comment: By `Seq("0", "-1", "-2", "-3")` you mean `["0", "-1", "-2", "-3"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the withColumn function:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 df.withColumn("attempt", lit(Array("-0","-1","-2","-3")))
```

Comment: Above solution will give following error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(-0, -1, -2, -3)
`

Comment: Sorry it's Array instead of Seq, i changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add using the typedLit(Spark version > 2.2).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
df.withColumn("attempt", typedLit(Seq("-0", "-1", "-2", "-3")))
```